# How can I make 'lnext' run 'lfirst' if it needs to be?

Tags: quickfix

I use [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) for finding syntax errors in code in vim, which populates the loclist with any errors found. However, when I first open a file with errors, which populates that list (I have `g:ale_lint_on_enter` set to `1`), no error is highlighted. I like to move between errors using `:lnext` and `:lprevious` (in fact I have them bound to keys), but neither will move to the first error! I have to do this with `:lfirst`. Only then will `:lnext` and `:lprevious` move between the errors in this file.

How can I make `:lnext` and `:lprevious` do this automatically so I don't have to use `:lfirst` first to get going?

(To be clear, I don't think this is anything specific to ALE, I think it's anything that populates the loclist. The same behaviour may also occur for the quickfix list, I haven't checked.)

Comment: After running `:lvimgrep` the first match is selected for me (no need for `:lfirst`). So from my point of view you need this for ALE not the builtin commands which populate the location list . Does `:ll` highlight the first error in the file? Maybe `nmap ]l :ll|ln` does the trick. I noticed that ALE provides dedicated `<Plug>(ale_next)` and `<Plug>(ale_previous)` maybe they take into account that the first error may not be selected in the file but in the location list.

Comment: Interesting. So I see the same thing you do with `:lvimgrep`. So it looks like it may be an ALE issue after all. For now I've mapped like this: `nmap ]g <Plug>(ale_next_wrap)` (I'm also using `vim-unimpaired` so `]l` conflicts). That seems to work as I expected. Thanks.